# typedefs within a typedef

Tags: c++

I am wanting to have a typedef within in a typedef and wonder if it is possible?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

```
typedef std::vector<TypeA>*                           pVparticle;
typedef typename std::vector<TypeA>::iterator         VparticleItr;
typedef std::map<pVparticle, Neutrino* >*             pMapPartpNu;

//Compiler Error
typedef NeutrinoFunctor< VparticleItr,  pMapPartpNu > partNuFunctor;
```

Here is the compiler error I recieve from gnu gcc version 4.1.2

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'NeutrinoFunctor' with no type
```

doesn't look like what I am attempting is possible.

Comment: Looks like you haven't declared `NeutrinoFunctor` yet. Nothing to do with typedefs though.

Comment: You haven't declared NeutrinoFunctor anywhere, how is the compiler to know what type partNuFunctor is supposed to be?

Comment: Just to make it clear: you *can* use typedefs within a typedef. This isn’t the issue here.

Comment: Also: Why `std::vector<TypeA>*`? The whole point of using STL and containers is, not to deal with naked pointers.

Comment: That's a very old version of GCC. Even Mac OS X 10.6 shipped with 4.2.1. If you want to try experimenting with the language, you might upgrade that.

Comment: Sorry guys. My NeutrinoFunctor header file had a typo in the include :-/

Comment: This is the version that scientific linux comes with I haven't got a choice withe GCC version :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible because you have no declaration of `NeutrinoFunctor` before the typedef.

The following code, using typedefs within typedefs, is legal:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct Foo {};

typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
typedef std::string String;

typedef Foo<String, IntVector> Bar;

int main() {

  Bar b;

}
```

Comment: I'd be interested in knowing the reason(s) for the downvote. If there is something wrong with my answer, I would gladly fix it!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to `typedef` another `typedef` (if that is even the right verbage) because the compiler thinks it is just another `type`. However, your compiler error is due to the fact that it does not know what is `NeutrinoFunctor`.